# php pdo FETCH_CLASS

Tags: php, pdo

why some additional properties are getting set for my value object. (id, username, password are public properties, but 0, 1 and 2 are unknown) (Edit: it seems fetch_class is not working since result is an array)

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [0] => 2
    [username] => john
    [1] => john
    [password] => $2y$10$xwkcBnXySe0jvHzFuN0OUeBvINQM33FUI0Ztnt0vNGgsQN/1ndGwe
    [2] => $2y$10$xwkcBnXySe0jvHzFuN0OUeBvINQM33FUI0Ztnt0vNGgsQN/1ndGwe
)
```

UserVO

```
namespace modules\positivo\model\valueObjects;

class UserVO {

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;

    function __construct() {
    }
}
```

my fetch class inside a namespace (PDO uses `\`)

```
protected function getUserVO($username) {
    $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM `user` WHERE username = :username AND suspended = 0 AND deleted = 0");
    $statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'UserVO');
    echo "<pre>";
    if($statement->execute(array('username' => $username))) {
        while($obj = $statement->fetch()) {
            print_r($obj);
            echo "<hr>";
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a \ before `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`?

Comment: because my fetch class is using namespace

Comment: Is "UserVO" in the global namespace? It may need to be fully qualified. `setFetchMode` will return false on error. You may want to see if that call is succeeding.

Comment: @KingIsaac you're right, I edited the namespace that UserVO uses, how can we pass that as a string to setFetchMode?

Comment: If you're using php 5.5 you can use the class resolution operator: `UserVO::class` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class). Otherwise you can create a static method `UserVO::getQualifiedClassName()`. Or put a const property: `UserVO::CLASS_NAME`. I usually do the former because the const property has caused me grief in the past.

Comment: @KingIsaac $statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, '\modules\positivo\model\valueObjects\UserVO'); fixed the problem, used the fully qualified name, Thanks for your helpful comments.